# Using non-SSR Vue module from Vuepress - how to deactivate imports?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuepress

Due to server-side rendering, `vuepress` can't use `vue` components which import libraries relying on the DOM.

i.e. this doesn't work because `mapbox-gl` needs access to the DOM on import:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
```

The suggested solution is to use dynamic imports in the `created()` hook, e.g.

```
created () {
  import('mapbox-gl').then(MapboxModule => {
    window.mapboxgl = MapboxModule.default
  }
}
```

<del>However, I've not been able to get dynamic imports working properly with module bundling.</del> [EDIT](After a false start the dynamic imports method does work.)

A different strategy might be to load the `mapbox-gl` script using the `vuepress` `config.js` head section. For example, in my `docs/.vuepress/config.js` file I've got:

```
head: [
    ['link', {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      type: 'text/css',
      href: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css'
    }],
    ['script', {
      src: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'
    }]
  ],
```

Aside from the `import` statement, the entirety of the component can then be used as normal because the `mapboxgl` variable is available in the `window` namespace.

Hence my question: Is there a simple and elegant manner to deactivate the `import` statement specifically for use from `vuepress`?

My current solution involves creating a base component with no imports (for use from `vuepress`), and then extending this in another component which then explicitly imports and registers the global variables, e.g.

```
<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl
// eslint-disable-next-line
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'
window.MapboxGeocoder = MapboxGeocoder
// eslint-disable-next-line
import MyComponentBase from './MyComponentBase.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  extends: MyComponentBase
}
</script>
```

Comment: _"I've not been able to get dynamic imports working properly"_  can you expand on this?

Comment: @Phil found a section where I accidentally instanced the map outside of the returned Promise (i.e. it was previously giving the Map not found error...). Editing the question.